# Error C2146: syntax error with my definition

Tags: c++

I have a problem in my `Mng.h` file like this
`Error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'it_Data'` & `val_Data` & `it_Ref` & `val_Ref`

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
template <class T> class CMng
{
protected:

typedef std::map<std::string, T*>::iterator     it_Data;
typedef std::map<std::string, T*>::value_type   val_Data;

typedef std::map<T*, int>::iterator             it_Ref;
typedef std::map<T*, int>::value_type           val_Ref;
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the file include any other headers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Don't forget `const_iterator`. And if T is a template, put the typedefs insider the class declaration.

Comment: `typedef typename std::map<std::string, T*>::iterator     it_Data;`. See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @cpplearner ist working thank you so much :)